# How to remove java packages from jdk

Tags: java

I want to keep only `java util`, `io`, `nio`and `math` packages and want to remove all other packages like `java.sql` and others from my JDK.

How can I remove them?

- So if I write some program which import removed packages it will give
  error package doesn't exist.

Comment: Why? WHY? **WHY?**

Comment: :)  yeah, why?  If you're trying to keep your memory footprint low, you might want to consider other languages!  I'm going to go and delete stuff from the JDK and see what happens.

Comment: This has _nothing to do_ with the memory footprint. Those classes live in the JRE - they are not part of the program and not loaded if they are not used.

Comment: I'm working on a project(web application) which will accept client's code in java, execute it on server and return the output to client. I am going to support only basic console based code no graphics, no sockets nothing else that's why.

Comment: In that case you need to use a `SecurityManager`; not hack the JRE.

Comment: You need to create a parser to check the input, not to alter the underneath of java. Don't try to overkill the problem

Comment: *"I want to keep only `java util`, `io`, `nio`.."* *"..I am going to support only basic console based code.."*  A malicious user with access to the classes of the `io` and `nio` can do a lot of damage.  Better to look to a `SecurityManager` as suggested elsewhere.  Also, that comment should be edited into the question.  It is relevant information - needed to come to the best solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. There is no such tool, AFAIK.
2. Removing stuff from the Java libraries can be technically tricky, 'cos it can be difficult to know if your code might directly or indirectly use some class or method.
3. There are potentially "licensing issues" if you add or remove classes from a JRE installer, and ship it to other people.

---

Concerning your proposed use case.

1. If you are building this as a web application, then you are going to have a lot of difficulty cutting out classes that are not needed.  A typical webapp server-side framework uses a lot of Java SE interfaces.
2. If you accepted and ran code someone who wanted to try and bring down your service, they could do it without using only the `Object` class.  (Hint: infinite loops and filling the heap.)  Running untrusted code on your server is a bad idea.  Period.
3. Think about the consequence for someone trying to run legitimate code on your server.  Why shouldn't they be allowed to use library classes / methods?  (I'd certainly be a bit miffed if I couldn't use "ordinary" library classes ...)

My advice would be reconsider if it was a good idea to implement such a service at all ... given the risks, and the difficulty you could have if your safeguards were ineffective.  If you decide to proceed, I advise running the untrusted code within the JVM in a security box.  As a second level of defence in case Java security is compromised, I'd recommend running the service "chrooted" or better still in an isolated  virtual machine that can be turned off if you run into problems.

Answer (score 2):

Use a SecurityManager instead of hacking the JDK

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to give you the best answer I can.

**Why you really shouldn't be doing what you want to do**

---

When you're writing code, it is commonly agreed to develop that code in a way that is extendable. That is, your code can be plugged into other applications, or it can be changed and added to, very easily. Now with that principle in mind, let's review what happens when you delete the possible functionality of your program. Say you delete the SQL package, and in the future, you want a backend database to provide some persistence in your program. You're screwed.

The idea of Java, in fact I'd go as far as to say the major advantage of Java, is it's commonality, consistency and standardization of patterns. A getter is always a getter. A variable (that isn't a constant) starts with a lower case letter. Classes have a standardized way of being structured. All these things make developing in Java quite intuitive.

The JDK is part of that consistency, and to edit it is to really impact one of the major points of Java. It sounds like you want to implement your program in a different, more compact language.

Finally, you have no idea how the client may want to extend your project in the future. IF you want to have some repeatable business from the client, and generate a good reputation at the same time, you want to design your code with good design practise in mind.